# How to report a proven wrong answer on Super User

Tags: discussion

This question has the actually correct answer directly beneath the wrongly as correct marked answer:

[How to turn off spelling and grammar check in OneNote on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/976329/how-to-turn-off-spelling-and-grammar-check-in-onenote-on-windows-10)

Can this somehow be changed?

Comment: Related: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7764/how-to-deal-with-an-answer-that-is-popular-but-wrong?rq=1

Comment: The author of the question gets to put the checkmark on the question he believes is right. The community say which is right by the amount of likes on the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to common sense, an answer being accepted doesn't always mean it's correct. It just means that the answer was considered the most helpful/best **for the OP** at that time.

Considering that there's [a comment to revisit the accepted answer on July 26](https://superuser.com/questions/976329/how-to-turn-off-spelling-and-grammar-check-in-onenote-on-windows-10#comment1807249_976329), and also considering that the OP is still active (last seen 15 hours ago at current writing), removing the acceptance mark by force can be considered as an abuse since it's OP's privilege to choose any answer that considered as the most helpful.

While there's an occurrence of unacceptance by a mod on another site, it's not a usual case that the mod will lightly follow. So, **don't** flag the answer being wrongly-accepted because it's not mods' task to decide the technical correctness of an answer.

Instead, you can try to comment on the question again to ask OP to consider updating the acceptance. However, (and as said before,) OP is free to choose any answer they deem the best.

Comment: Have to ask there: Does this also apply if you find out the "wrong" answer opens pandoras box? (thus it leads to security Problems and opens up your pc to attacks, ... as example,   or that it could cause pc crashes, ....).

Comment: @Thomas That would be a somewhat special case that doesn't occur often.  Mods should not judge the technical nature of an answer. It could be blatantly wrong or cause problems, but that doesn't mean it should be deleted. If there are severe issues, adding a comment or -- but this could be considered too strong intervention -- editing the post to include a caveat would be the preferable option.

Comment: Minor clarification: moderators do not have the ability to directly revoke the accepted status from an answer ([relevant MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111529/295684)). I suspect deleting and undeleting an answer might remove the checkmark, but as you said, mods should not judge technical accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

- Downvote the wrong answer
- Upvote the correct answer
- Add a comment to the wrong answer explaining why do you think it is incorrect.
- IF and only IF you are experienced and convinced that you are right and have proof to back up your opinion. Edit the the wrong answer (without completely rewriting it).

Comment: None of your suggested solutions works for the OP, as they have insufficient reputation. Also, a completely wrong answer shouldn't be edited by someone else to make it right, as that would definitely change the meaning of the post. Better to downvote and leave a comment, or provide another, correct answer.

Comment: @slhck Any user can suggest an edit to an answer

Comment: @Ramhound I meant, "none of your first three suggested solutions"; editing is a special case obviously.

Comment: @slhck - Just because the author doesn't have the reputation to vote or leave a comment does not mean it isn't the *correct* action.  If they cannot do the *correct* action then they do nothing until they can.  There should be a fifth item in the list, which of course be, do nothing if your unable to do any of the other options.